# Use variable in reference with remote in Org-table

Tags: org-mode, org-table, remote

I have one table called GRADING containing names and points entered by hand, and another table (FOO) containing the grading scheme. Is there a simple formula which allows to lookup the number of points and assign the corresponding grade from FOO? I have tried many variation of the formula `$3=remote(FOO,@@#$2)`. If we could replace `@#` by `$2` I think it would do the trick, but everything gets messed up.

```
#+NAME: GRADING
| Name  | Points | Grade |
|-------+--------+-------|
| Alice |     10 |       |
| Rob   |     20 |       |
| Bob   |     30 |       |
| Jack  |     35 |       |
| Marc  |     12 |       |
| Marie |     65 |       |
| Fanny |     12 |       |
#+TBLFM: $3=remote(FOO,@@#$2)


#+NAME: FOO
| Number of points | Grade |
|------------------+-------|
|                0 |     1 |
|                1 |     1 |
|                2 |     1 |
|                3 |   1.5 |
|                4 |   1.5 |
|                5 |   1.5 |
|                6 |   1.5 |
|                7 |   1.5 |
|                8 |   1.5 |
|                9 |   1.5 |
|               10 |     2 |
|               11 |     2 |
|               12 |     2 |
|               13 |     2 |
|               14 |     2 |
|               15 |     2 |
|               16 |     2 |
|               17 |   2.5 |
|               18 |   2.5 |
|               19 |   2.5 |
|               20 |   2.5 |
|               21 |   2.5 |
|               22 |   2.5 |
|               23 |   2.5 |
|               24 |     3 |
|               25 |     3 |
|               26 |     3 |
|               27 |     3 |
|               28 |     3 |
|               29 |     3 |
|               30 |     3 |
|               31 |     3 |
|               32 |     3 |
|               33 |   3.5 |
|               34 |   3.5 |
|               35 |   3.5 |
|               36 |   3.5 |
|               37 |   3.5 |
|               38 |   3.5 |
|               39 |   3.5 |
|               40 |   3.5 |
|               41 |   3.5 |
|               42 |     4 |
|               43 |     4 |
|               44 |     4 |
|               45 |     4 |
|               46 |     4 |
|               47 |     4 |
|               48 |     4 |
|               49 |   4.5 |
|               50 |   4.5 |
|               51 |   4.5 |
|               52 |   4.5 |
|               53 |   4.5 |
|               54 |   4.5 |
|               55 |   4.5 |
|               56 |     5 |
|               57 |     5 |
|               58 |     5 |
|               59 |     5 |
|               60 |     5 |
|               61 |   5.5 |
|               62 |   5.5 |
|               63 |   5.5 |
|               64 |   5.5 |
|               65 |   5.5 |
|               66 |     6 |
|               67 |     6 |
|               68 |     6 |
|               69 |     6 |
|               70 |     6 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will be useful to someone (have been searching for the solution for hours!). The function to use is `#+TBLFM: $3='(org-lookup-first $2 '(remote(FOO,@2$1..@>$1)) '(remote(FOO,@2$2..@>$2)))`

Found it by reading this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10954/generate-populate-table-in-org-mode-using-org-lookup-all) which links to the [org lookup functions documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Lookup-functions.html), which in turn links to [useful examples in Worg](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-lookups.html).